# How to query multiple tables in a MySQL Database using PHP, and using jQuery to display results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, database

I have a paginated Listview in jQuery Mobile and it is creating a grid of artist thumbnails from DB Table 1 "Artists" which contains 143 artist names and an initial picture and bio (this part works). Then Table 2 "Artworks" has all the remaining (1006) artworks.

How do I pull in the associated artist artworks, should I be using joins or referencing the "artistId" (foreign key in the Artworks table) instead of the "id" (the primary key in the Artist table)?

DB Structure and data example Example:

Table 1 - Artists

```
id, artistId, firstName, lastName,  bio, category, officePhone, audio, email, city, picture
14, 1-2alas, 2alas, ,2Alas Is a collective., Mural ,555-1212, 2Alas.mp3, 2alas@gmail.com, Miami, IMG_2521.jpg
```

Table 2 - Artworks

```
id,  artistId,  firstName,  lastName,  imageName , latitude,  longitude , category
23, 1-2alas, 2alas, , IMG_2521.jpg, 25.800575, -80.200933, Mural
24, 1-2alas, 2alas, , IMG_2596.jpg, 25.800775, -80.196627, Mural
25, 1-2alas, 2alas, , IMG_2760.jpg, 25.799992, -80.196270, Mural
```

Code:

```
    <?php

error_reporting(0);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usr","pass","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$perPage    = $_REQUEST['listomatic']['perPage'];
$listOffset = $_REQUEST['listomatic']['listOffset'];
$searchTerm = $_REQUEST['listomatic']['searchTerm'];

if ($searchTerm) {
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
            FROM artists
            WHERE firstName LIKE '%$searchTerm%'
            ORDER BY firstName ASC
            LIMIT $listOffset, $perPage";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
            FROM artists
            ORDER BY firstName ASC
            LIMIT $listOffset, $perPage";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$resultNumRows = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as foundRows');
$rowFoundRows = mysqli_fetch_array($resultNumRows);
$iFoundRows = $rowFoundRows['foundRows'];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sDate = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($row['date']));
    $sPicture = ($row['picture']);
    $sFirstName = ($row['firstName']);
    $sLastName = ($row['lastName']);
    $sId = ($row['id']);
    // Listomatic requires the "total" field to show/hide the "Show More" button
    $aData['total'] = $iFoundRows; 
    // The following is sample data in the artist table that you want to display
    $aData['artists'][] = array('date' =>  $sDate,
                                'picture' => $sPicture,
                                'firstName' => $sFirstName,
                                'lastName' => $sLastName,
                                'id' => $sId
                                );
}
echo json_encode($aData);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Better fix that before you even start worrying about using joins or not.

Comment: @MarcB, thanks for the feedback, I clicked thru to your link, but do not know what I am looking for regarding preventing an injection any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: That site has prevention strategies/sample code for a LARGE number of languages, including php.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at the PHP samples. BTW this is copy paste code from a JQMobile module called listomatic.

Comment: generally, a LOT of php code examples on the web are utter crap.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data. Your carrying way too much redundancy.

Comment: @Strawberry can you give me an example of the redundancy you see in my tables so when I read about normalizing I will associate it properly?

Comment: @MarcB I read through the PHP examples and compared them to the copy paste samples, unfortunately I am not skilled enough to rewrite this based on your examples.

Comment: Well, in the artworks table three of the columns would appear to be redundant (and I meant "you're" earlier)

Comment: @MarcB I've read and re-read, but I do not know how to re-write this code without ISE 500 errors, can you help?